# How do i use linq as datasource for a Microsoft report

Tags: c#, linq, report

```
var exams = (from appointment in appointments select new {coursecode = (appointment.Tag as exam).ID}).ToList();

rpt.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsExam". exams.AsEnumerable()));
rpt.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
rpt.RefreshReport();
```

Each appointment object contains an exam object.
I would like to use the results of the linq query as the datasource of my report. However only the first row in IEnumerable exams is shown in the report even though it contains 81 rows. How can i fix this.

Comment: as a side note `List<T>` already implements `IEnumerable`, there's no need to use ` exams.AsEnumerable()`, just pass `exam`

Comment: First of all: what ORM are you using? Linq-to-SQL? Entity Framework (Linq-to-Entities)? Also: "Microsoft report" - do you mean a SQL Server Reporting Services report??

Comment: I am using (pretty much) the same code and works without problems. How does your `.rdlc` file look? Do you use a table? Do you have your `TextBox` in a `List`? There can be conditions that limit the collection to only display one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var exams = (from appointment in appointments
               select new
                    {
                          ((Exam)appointment.CustomFields["Field"]).Id,
                          ((Exam)appointment.CustomFields["Field"]).Name,
                          ((Exam)appointment.CustomFields["Field"]).Date,
                                     ((Exam)appointment.CustomFields["Field"]).Period.StartTime,
                                     ((Exam)appointment.CustomFields["Field"]).Period.EndTime,
                                     Location = ((Exam)appointment.CustomFields["Field"]).Location.Name
                                });

        SetDataSource(exams);


    private void SetDataSource(object exams)
    {          
        scheduleBindingSource.DataSource = exams;
        this.rpTTViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
        this.rpTTViewer.RefreshReport(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code as below for your purpose :

```
//Create a dataset typed
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//Constructor a dataset from Dataset Model, dataset use for crystal report
DataSet1.print_salesDataTable tb = new DataSet1.print_salesDataTable();

//Queries with the conditions is ID
QLGiayDepEntities list = new QLGiayDepEntities();
var result = (from n in list.print_sales
              where n.OrderID == txtID.Text
              select n).ToList();

//Fill result to table
foreach (print_sales item in result)
{
    tb.Rows.Add(
        item.OrderID,
        item.DateOrder,
        item.NameEmployee,
        item.Total,
        item.Recieved,
        item.Discount,
        item.Sum,
        item.FromCustomer,
        item.Notes,
        item.Barcode,
        item.Name,
        item.ColorName,
        item.SizeID,
        item.Quantity,
        item.Price,
        item.SubTotal);
}

//checking to print
if (result == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("null");
}
else
{
    ds.Tables.Add(tb);
    CrystalReportSales1.SetDataSource(ds);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalReportSales1;
    crystalReportViewer1.PrintReport();
}
```